# The set of all philosophers is a camel

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, logic

In Wilder's book "Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics," a "proof" for the statement: "The set of all philosophers is a camel" is mentioned in passing as something done by Grelling under the Russel paradox section. Does anyone know how to go about doing this or point me to a place where it is done? I tried looking up the book or article but all of Grelling's stuff seems to be in German. I thought this was pretty funny/interesting!

Comment: Wilder's citation point at the booklet (49 pages) by Kurt Grelling, *Mengenlehre* (1924), page 40-on : *Die Antinomien der Mengenlehre*. Unfortunately, it is not possible to browse it in GoogleBooks. I've found only a spanish translation of it : Teoría de los conjuntos (1943), but also in this case I cannot find an elctronic copy of it.

Comment: That's too bad. I will look at the library and post any findings. Afraid my Spanish is very untechnical.